# How to set local state with flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have a Flutter app that uses Bloc pattern for state management.

I have a local variable in a page that stores state.

`PageA:`

```dart
// Outside build function 
List<String> _names = []; // local variable to show the changes visually
.
.
.
// Inside build function
return Scaffold(
 body: BlocConsumer<PageABloc, PageAState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is PageASuccessState) { 
            _names = state.names;                              // here is problem
            return _body();
          } else if (state is PageALoadingState ||
              state is PageAInitState) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else
            return Center(child: Text("Something went wrong"));
        },
        listener: (context, state) {},
      ),
);
```

I need to only update state of `state.names` when **user clicks on a *save* button** that is in `_body()`, but to show the visual changes to user, I'm using `_names` local variable.

How to load the initial values of `state.names` to `_names`?

The code that I tried doesn't work as it resets any changes to `_names`(local) on every frame.

I tried something like,

```dart
if (state is PageASuccessState) { 
            final List<String> _n = state.names;
            _names.addAll(_n);
            return _body(_width);
   }
```

But this just adds `state.names` repeatedly to `_names`, infinite number of times.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your state is containing the `names` list every time builder of BlocBuilder is called.

You should replace `List<String> _names = []` with `LinkedHashSet<String> _names = LinkedHashSet<String>()`;

LinkedHashSet will work exactly like list but it won't allow duplicates. You can change it to list by calling
`_names.iterator.toList();` anytime you want.